# How do I correctly use the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently attempting to manually remove 2FA for my GitLab server's administrator account, since I've lost access to both my OTP app, and the recovery keys for the account.

There is only one account with administrator access.

According to [this comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1960#note_1606745), the correct way to do this is to set `otp_required_for_login` to `false` for that user.

I have found my way into the database debug console (`sudo gitlab-rails dbconsole`; it's basically a wrapper for `psql`), and am now trying to actually change the value. However, I get a syntax error when running my query.

My query:

```
UPDATE "users"
  SET "otp_required_for_login" = false
  WHERE username = "gl_administrator";
```

The syntax error I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""gl_administrator""
LINE 3: WHERE username = "gl_administrator";
                         ^
```

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for string literals, double quotes are for identifiers (such as table and column names) that require quoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use single-quotes when referencing a string literal.

So, your query would simply change to:

```
WHERE username = 'gl_administrator';
```